# Lego Star Wars The Force Awakens crash when trying to start the game

Tags: technical-issues, lego-star-wars-the-force-awakens

Game was running perfectly, Windows 10, until 7.1%. Now when I try to load the game or try "new game" or "continue game" the screen is just black with the music in the background.

Comment: Did you had any update? From the issue, it could be a graphic driver issue

Comment: Are you using Steam? If you are, try uninstalling the game and reinstalling it.